How to obtain financial data legally for business uses?
I am working on a project to design some strategy based on the financial data of stocks. I want to design a website and making it publically available, but I am not sure if I can used scraped data from NASDAQ,TradingView etc. for business purpose.

Anything you can scrape from a public website is by definition not insider information. What does this have to do with insider trading?

What legal terminology do you have a question about?

And what does it have to do with customer service? Your tags seem to be mostly unrelated to the question.

You should read the end-user license of the sites you want to scrape from, they'll explain what they allow you to do.

All public filings of publicly traded companies (including all companies listed on any stock exchange including the NASDAQ) are available from the Securities and Exchange Commission's EDGAR database.

This doesn't seem to answer OP's question (can they legally used scraped data for business purposes?).

@JBentley Federal government data is in the public domain.

If you need timely intra-day financial data as well as historical data and analysis, look at commercial data providers for the financial services industry such as Refinitiv (LSEG.com) to see what data are available, terms of use and how much it costs.
